# Easiest way to replace a substring in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Whats the easiest way in javascript to replace ABC, DEF, GHI with XYZ in the following strings

```
http://z.site.com/z/ABC/z/z.html
http://z.site.com/z/DEF/z/z.html
http://z.site.com/z/GHI/z/z.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to detect that pattern and change the three letters in question:

```
s = s.replace(/^http:\/\/z\.site\.com\/z\/.../, 'http://z.site.com/z/XYZ');
```

Comment: I use $1 to get the beginning since the subdomain and the first /z MAY change.

Answer (score 4):

```
var url = "http://z.site.com/z/ABC/z/z.html";
url = url.replace(/ABC|DEF|GHI/, "XYZ");
```

Comment: Funny, there are 0 views on this page.